Given two ordinals, one is a subset of the other
I have an issue trying to understand the proof of Theorem $1$. in this post on Terry Tao's blog regarding ordinals. Specifically, if $\alpha$, $\beta$ are ordinals I want to show that one is a subset of the other. Here ordinals are defined as well ordered sets $\alpha$, such that $\{y \in \alpha : y < x \}$ for all $x \in \alpha$. Since there is always a order preserving embedding $\varphi: \alpha \to \beta$ (WLOG in this direction) between well orderings and this ordering is unique, it is enough to show $\varphi$ is the identity mapping. According to the blog one can now show $\varphi(x) = x$ by using strong induction. Can somebody elaborate how induction is applied here? Specifically the strong induction from the blog , that does not distuinguish cases (Exercise $1$).

Assume for any y < x  φ(y) = y then y < x implies φ(y) < φ(x), y < φ(x) and z < φ(x), implies that z = φ(w) < φ(x) and w <  x, by IH φ(w) = w = z, so z < x.

The key ideas are that function is fixed below x ( Strong Inductive Hypothesis) and that for ordinals < is equivalent to elementhood, and that we have a order preserving map
